# what does 'live up to the buzz' stand for?

Tags: phrases

I recently read an article about honey

> As I was reflecting on all the health benefits of honey, it suddenly occurred to me: I don't think I've ever seen a sick bee. Coincidence? Probably. But honey may be one miracle cure that lives up to the buzz.

according to (www.thefreedictionary.com), it means "to fulfill expectations; to satisfy a goal or set of goals" but I hardly put that on the context here.

Comment: It's a slightly "odd" usage, solely motivated by the punning potential. The normal word there would be ***hype***, not ***buzz***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'Buzz' is used quite often in AmE in the sense of 'hype', 'gossip'.

Comment: @Erik Kowal: I specifically said "slightly" because I knew *someone* would say OP's version was "normal". But it's [too rare to graph in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+up+to+the+hype%2Clive+up+to+the+buzz&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20up%20to%20the%20hype%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Google Books estimates [*live up to the buzz*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+up+to+the+buzz%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):416 hits, [*live up to the hype*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+up+to+the+hype%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl):13,500 hits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Fair enough. (And thanks for running the searches.)

Comment: No one ever needed to tell me of my compatriots everywhere I had ever been what "buzz" and "living up to" mean. It is within the capacity of normal human intellect to connect the two together. Like the ability to connect "Getting off" and "the couch".

Comment: I'm not sure there's a real disagreement here:  The slang term *the buzz* is relatively common, the usage of it in the phrase "living up to *the buzz*" is relatively rare, and almost certainly motivated primarily by the desire to make a pun.  Everyone is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The buzz* is the sound of many people talking about something, it's a playful slang idiom that generally means something is the subject of positive rumors.  "Living up to the buzz" is indeed fulfilling expectations --the expectations created by those rumors.

In this case, the phrase is used especially because bees also make a buzzing sound.

Comment: Incidentally, there are many sick and dying bees. There have been huge "die-offs", and entire colonies have disappeared; the term is "colony collapse disorder" (CCD).  Certain pesticides, particularly neonicotinoids (or "neonics" for short) are suspected culprits,